# Ensure max min columns don't overlap

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Let's say I have the following Categories table:

```
Category  MinValue  MaxValue
A         1         2
B         3         9
C         10        0
```

Above I'm using 0 to indicate no maximum. These values will be configurable by end users. They will be able to add and remove categories, and modify the max and min values. Is there any sort of a constraint I can place on the table to ensure that no two ranges overlap?

This table will be modified using a web application so I could pre-validate changes to the table using Javascript so even an algorithm to prevent duplicates might suffice.

Comment: I would suggest using a `null` to represent no value, rather than a 0.

Comment: @podiluska That's true null would probably be better but I need to represent it in some way in the UI. I'll figure that out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the obvious here, but I don't think this is easy in Oracle.

I've seen solutions using a materialized view

- that contains the overlaps from the Categories table
- is refresh on commit
- has a check constraint that it not contain any rows. This can be achieved by having a "rownum" column in the materialized view and a check constraint that this "rownum" column's value is always 0.

The check constraint on the materialized will then be violated *on commit* if a user enters any overlapping data.

You'll need to write your front end to allow for exceptions to be raised by Oracle on commit and to present an appropriate message to the user.

Now in the latest version of Postgresql for example, this is very easy with exclusion constraints.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts on this but to be honest the data is going to be very static in this case. It will rarely change. I've decided not to bother enforcing validation on the data as it's not worth the hassle. However thinking about it in the first place made me think it was worth a question on here. I'll leave this going for a few days and I'll accept this if it remains the best answer. I prbably won't use it though.

Comment: Then it's probably sufficient to make a PL/SQL procedure or function that checks that no data overlaps. Call this after the data has changed to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it with a constraint, but you should be able to create a `before insert/update` trigger and use `raise_application_error` to abort the insert if it violates the conditions.

Something like...

```
if exists (select * from yourtable where :new.minvalue<maxvalue and :new.maxvalue>minvalue)
begin
   raise_application_error(...)
end
```

Comment: Triggers won't see data from other users' in-progress transactions, so this is a dangerous approach in an environment where many concurrent updates are expected. It may be acceptable for this user's situation, I don't know.

Comment: Adding a call to dbms_lock before the test would fix this though. Just make sure you obtain a lock that is released on commit.